# Synchronizing iPhoto Libraries

Tags: rsync, iphoto

My wife and I both maintain separate iPhoto libraries on our laptops.  We both have our creative differences about how the libraries should be maintained.  :)

I have a G5 tower downstairs that serves as our general use workstation/server.  I'd like to set up an rsync job to synchronize both libraries to one master library downstairs.  I'm not sure where to start in a way that would make sure the new "Master" library is actually usable in iPhoto.

Now that I type this, I guess I could sync both libraries separately, then occasionally merge them manually...  I guess I'd like a fully automated solution if possible.  I "think" this would be possible with rsync, just don't know enough about the iPhoto library database to know which rsync options would be best.

Comment: I would also like to know this, as I want to sync a single iphoto library across 4 logins (2 accounts on 2 computers each) so that either of us can access the library on either computer. People have mentioned dropbox solutions, but my library is getting pretty big.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best I could come up with was using rsync to sync both libraries to the workstation/server downstairs, and manually merge the photos.  Tedious, yes, but couldn't find any other way.

Answer (score 0):

[iPhoto Library Manager](http://www.fatcatsoftware.com/iplm/) could be an option...

> iPhoto Library Manager allows you to organize your photos among
>   multiple iPhoto libraries, rather than having to store all of your
>   photos in one giant library.
>
> iPhoto Library Manager lets you easily create and keep track of
>   multiple iPhoto libraries, but that's only the beginning. It also has
>   the ability to copy your photos from one library to another, while
>   keeping track of photo metadata that is normally lost when exporting
>   from one library and importing into another.
>
> Titles, dates, descriptions, keywords, ratings, faces, and place
>   information are all transferred along with the photos, ensuring that
>   you keep all that information you spent hours entering into iPhoto.
>   iPhoto Library Manager also reconstructs events and albums with the
>   same photos as they had in the library they came from, as well as
>   retaining both the edited and original copies of each photo. You can
>   split up a large library into multiple smaller libraries, merge entire
>   libraries together into a big one, and much more

[image]